# Review statistics analysis

Tags: discussion, review, statistics

Is there anyway for a normal reviewer to get any feedback on their reviewing technique?

I know Google Analytics takes statistics on like **everything**, so can I see some?

Comment: I did not find what GA means neither [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/common-acronyms-used-on-main-and-meta) nor [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).

Comment: Since you mentioned Google Analytics, there is site analytics page which shows stats like numbers of posts, votes, traffic, traffic sources, so somewhat similar to GA. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21347/what-are-the-current-traffic-and-usage-patterns-of-this-site) for details. But no stats  on reviews are shown there. So this is not what you want if you are looking for data which could help you "review your reviews".

Comment: Moderators can see some stats of your reviews (per review queue). For example about closing queue we can see: how many times you voted to close/leave open, average time spent per review, number of edits while reviewing, as well as how well you handled the review audits. We cannot see data about how much in line your reviews are with those of the others.

Comment: [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/160352/your-edit-reviews)'s a minor something you can find on SEDE: It lists counts of times you approved an edit but the edit was rejected, etc. Not a ton of information, and the fact that two to three people agreed on the approval/disapproval certainly doesn't mean it was necessarily the "right" decision. Either way, it's some data -- but only for suggested edits.